# What tools are there that help build expression trees for dynamic LINQ queries?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

My project needs to let users build their own dynamic queries.  From what I've read, Expression Trees are the way to go.  However the syntax is rather complicated.

I envision having a GUI where users would be able to check tables, select columns, specify parameters,etc and then build a string such as:

```
            var myQuery =
                from P in context.Projects
                join UA in context.UserAttributes on P.ProjectID equals UA.ProjectID
                join UBA in context.UserBooleanAttributes on UA.UserAttributeID equals UBA.UserAttributeID
                join U in context.Users on UBA.UserID equals U.UserID
                where P.ProjectID == 1
                where UBA.Value == true
                where (UA.UserAttributeID == 1 || UA.UserAttributeID == 2)
                select new { uba = U };
```

And store that in a queries table.  To process the query, I was hoping there is some library out there that will magically do something like:

```
var result = magic(str);
foreach(var user in result)
   Foo(user.Email);
```

In this example I know that all my queries would return Users, but for other queries I would probably have to use reflection or in another column specify the expected type in results.

I found one project called LinqTextQueryBuilder which looks interesting, but I wanted to see if there are other alternatives.

Comment: Erm...that isn't a Linq Expression. That is like...um...C#. You want a C# compiler/parser/code editor.

Comment: Well, it's not a lambda expression to be sure.  LINQ TO SQL

Comment: Given the context, it's most likely NOT LinqToSQL.

Comment: And no... The string is C#, not an expression.

Comment: I'm not sure introducing another level of indirection to create a SQL statement is the best idea.  Why not just create the SQL directly?

Comment: You can also consider using Entity SQL.

Comment: https://linqtextquerybuilder.codeplex.com, which is using c# syntax in a string.  Just looking to see if there is anything else out there like this

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit could you explain how this is better than giving your users access to the SQL database? In fact how is it different? Well apart from opening up the server to C# injection as well as your server to SQL injection.